# polyglossia adds extra kerning to csquotes

Tags: spacing, punctuation, polyglossia, csquotes

When I use `csquotes` with `polyglossia`, an extra kerning is added after the first quotation mark. `\enquote{Werk}` becomes `„ Werk“`, not `„Werk“`. This doesn't look nice, especially when you have a word starting with a letter like `w`. When I use `babel` instead, `csquotes` works fine (`„Werk“`). Can anyone help to prevent `csquotes` (or `polyglossia`?) from inserting an extra space when using `polyglossia` (and running `xelatex`)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Werk

\enquote{Werk}

„Werk“

\end{document}
```

Comment: With an updated Polyglossia (version 1.2.0cc) this doesn't happen. It doesn't happen with TeX Live 2010 either.

Comment: I am using polyglossia 1.2.0cc with an freshly updated TeX Live 2011, and it actually does happen. Have you run my example? The extra space is even bigger when I use smaller fonts like MinionPro (add `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}` ).

Comment: I see it too (miktex 2.9) and I suggest that you contact the author of csquotes. He knows best where to look for the place where the kerning is distroyed.

Comment: Yes, now I see it, too.

Answer (score 6):

This issue has been fixed in [csquotes](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) v5.1d, released October 22th, 2011.